# How can I test a GPU completely to ensure all of it's components work properly?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, defective-hardware

I was unable to find a solution to this on Superuser, the GPU isn't overheating nor is it crashing, it simply provides wrong output and practically explodes sometimes.

I need to find a tool which can help diagnose and possibly pinpoint what is going on. The problem is that with each load it's something different, and this spans multiple applications/games. Interestingly, even though IE9 is GPU accelerated, it does not seem to be suffering this issue - it may simply be that it's impact is too minimal to hit the point required.

Quick Specs:

---

- OS: Windows 7 home premium x64
- GPU: MSI Nvidia Geforce 560 GTX
- Motherboard: MSI 970a-G45

---

I hope these images aren't excessive, I'd collapse them if I could...

In each one the defects were very active. The first, objects were morphing, smoothly between some weird extremes in odd locations. The second is an example of static that kept getting applied to various objects which was also very active. The third was a stripe that seemd to be mostly static but moved with the camera, and the fourth was very active colorful spikes that would grow/shrink smoothly.

This is just a small selection of things that have happened, from strange shadows attached to the my mouse cursor projected inworld, to straight up screen explosions. I've had this before with dead GPU's but those also suffered heat issues. The hottest this GPU has achieved so far is 80ºC.

I looked into FurMark, but it doesn't really help detect defects. So I'm not sure where to go from here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[image: Dead Island, Busted]
[image: Left4Dead Static on specific objects]
[image: Dead Island, Orange Stripe]
[image: Dead Island, Colorful (moving) spikes]

Comment: Have you made sure that both of the power connectors on the card are plugged in?

Comment: Yeah, this happened only recently. I'm almost sure what Hand-E-Food said is correct. It worked great at first, then this without overheating. I live near train tracks so a loose connection would become worse with each train.

Comment: I suppose a cold-joint is possible, but if you have vibrational problems, then one of the power-connectors could have gotten loose as well. That is much easier (and cheaper) to check and fix.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not very skilled in the electrical realm, I wouldn't even know where to begin to look. Will have to look to see if they'll take it back.

Comment: You don't need to be an electrical engineer to make sure that both power-connectors are plugged into the card correctly; cords come loose all the time.

Comment: Ah,  I see what you meant, I thought you meant a power connection on the circuitboard itself. I can take a look at the GPU later and see if one has indeed come loose.

Comment: Alright. If a video-card is not getting enough power, it can lead to display corruption, especially in 3D games and such like above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue before.  It was a faulty video card, possibly a loose connection on the circuit board somewhere, essentially causing random numbers to appear in the data.  I highly recommend claiming it under warranty if you can.